# How to get multiple images from a prototype object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, javascript-objects

im trying to figure out how to get multiple image objects with a prototype object. I know for a fact I can get 1 instance of an image.. But I would like to declare multiple images from an array and then be able to make a instance out of them.. Below is a snippet of my code..Any help would be glady appreciated.. Thanks :)

```
        function SuperType(name){
        this.name = name;

        this.pictures = new Array();
        this.pictures = new Image();
        this.pictures[0].src = ["Desert.jpg"];

        this.pictures = new Image();
        this.pictures[1].src = ["Storm.jpg"];

    }

    SuperType.prototype.sayName = function(){
        alert(this.name);
    };

    function SubType(name, age){  
        SuperType.call(this, name);

        this.age = age;
    }

    SubType.prototype = new SuperType();

    SubType.prototype.sayAge = function(){
        alert(this.age);
    };

    var instance1 = new SubType("Nicholas", 29);

    document.getElementById("id0").appendChild(instance1.pictures[0])
    document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(instance1.pictures[1])
```

Comment: You’re replacing `this.pictures` with a `new Image()` before each image. Why?

Comment: Just how many values do you think one property can hold?

Comment: replace both instances of `this.pictures = new Image();` with `this.pictures.push(new Image());`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @ minitech, @ Crazy Train, your right im learning i can only assign one property to a value not multiple values.. And lastly @ Rory thanksss so much!! pushing each image into the array worked.. Much appreciated!!! :)

Comment: Also, your `pictures` is created anew for each instance of your type. Are you sure you didn't mean to do `SuperType.prototype.pictures = []; SuperType.prototype.pictures.push(new Image()); ...`?